Grouping 2D data using Python
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.xy_list = [x, y]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            if self.x in other.xy_list or self.y in other.xy_list:
                other.xy_list.append(self.x)
                other.xy_list.append(self.y)
                return True

        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x) + "--" + str(self.y)


def group_by_point(p_list):
    d = dict()
    for p in p_list:
        p_obj = Point(p[0], p[1])
        for k, val in d.items():
            if p_obj == k:
                d[k].append(p)
                break
        else:
            d[p_obj] = [p]

    for key in d:
        print(d[key])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p_list = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 5), (2, 9)]
    group_by_point(p_list)
    print("============")
    p_list = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (9, 10), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 6), (8, 2)]
    group_by_point(p_list)
    print("============")

The above is my code.
The first display is correct, while the second result is incorrect,
According to the existence of identical tuple elements in the list, or indirectly through elements in other tuples.
How can I modify my code to achieve the expected results.
input:
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5), (9, 10), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 6), (8, 2)]

output:
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (9, 10), (6, 7), (7, 9), (8, 6), (8, 2)]
[(4, 5)]

